# How to avoid Double values getting stored in 1Ex format?

Tags: java, double

I am having a double variable:

```
private double b=0.0;
```

I am taking value of a certain field in b (the value is between 0.0 to 9.99999999). Mostly, user enters value between 0.0 to 1.0.

When I am saving the value from user in 'b', and if the value is 0.000001, then it is getting saved as 1E-6 and next time displayed as same on the screen (this is because b is Double).

Is there any way (just by calling some method) in Java, that I can avoid the conversion of value to 1E-6 format? I want to save the value as entered by user only (0.000001).

Comment: 1Ex format is a display problem; the number is being stored the same either way.  Use an appropriate formatting string to display the number the way you want it.

Comment: Robert, can you tell me how to use appropriate formatting of String in this case?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The double isn't actually "saved" as a string at all. That's just a matter of formatting - for which you should see [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). However, it definitely won't be *exactly* 0.000001 because that number isn't exactly representable as a double. I would *strongly* recommend that you use [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead when precise decimal values matter (as it sounds like they do here).

Answer (score 2):

It's true that the number isn't stored in memory using the scientific (E) notation.

You can demonstrate this to yourself by formatting the number differently when you output it:

```
@Test
public void testLittle() {
    double myNum = 0.000001;
    System.out.printf("%f \n",myNum);
}
```

You should definitely heed other advice posted in answers here and use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if you really want the output to match the input, since some floating-point values aren't what 
 you think they are when representing them in a computer. (ref: [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754))

The "Java Puzzlers" presentations sometimes discuss these odd behaviors and are always a fun way to learn.  (See [this talk from Google I/O 2011](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/java-puzzlers-scraping-the-bottom-of-the-barrel.html), a bit after 3 minutes in)